# Java Runtime Environement on Windows 7, disable "Enable the next-generation Java Plug-in"

Tags: java

Starting from jre 1.6u10, browser integration uses a so-called "next-generation plugin". 


Some old applications are not compatible with it, and (on windows) **it could be disabled** in control panel, java, Advanced, Java Plug-in, remove the check from "Enable the next-generation Java Plug-in (requires browser restart)". 
The problem is that sometimes this check is grayed out, and it is not uncheckable even if you have amdinistrative priviledges and run as administrator.
Any workaround to solve this?

UPDATE:

I've done some testing on some machines with different operating systems, browsers and java versions. 
Initially I've supposed that the problem was w 7 or the fact that it was a 64 bit o.s., but there is a case (case 3) that denies this assumption. 
So there is something "else" on a machine that determines this option to be grayed out.

```
Test   O.S               Browser    JRE version    State 

  1    W 7 64 (Home)     IE 9       7u2   64       grayed out

  2    W 7 64 (Bus)      IE 8       6u27  64       grayed out

  3    W 7 64 (Bus)      IE 9       6u22  64       NOT grayed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first, simple, not extensively tested answser is:

On 64 bit machines, 64 bit JVMs have that flag grayed out (tested various releases >6.10 and <=7.2)
Installing 32 bit jvm, that flag will be not grayed out.
It is obvious that this solution is sub-optimal, but may be a (perhaps the only) solution for some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

While looking for exactly the same thing I found a forum post with another clue, more strangeness:

> If you can't untick it because it is grayed out, highlight the entry
>   and press space bar

This does successfully remove the tick from the Plug-in box, but the next time the Java Control Panel is opened, it reverts back to "ticked".

The original forum post is here:
 http://www.sevenforums.com/software/208418-removed-java-add-still-ie9.html#post1754583

Answer (score 0):

You can also click the "add" button, and voila! you can now un-check BOTH boxes for Java and the "new" blank added item.